# nslookup not working for some domains on my server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns, nslookup

nslookup not working for some domains on my server.  It's weird from my desktop these domain names work with nslookup but from my server they don't.  This is causing me all kinds of problems.

Anyone else ever run into this problem?

Comment: Please provide the output of "ipconfig /all" from the client and the server.  Also include the output of "nslookup" from the client and the server showing us the differences in behaviour.  Without specific examples, we can only guess at what your problem really is.  Help us to help you.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You've probably checked this already, but are you pointing to the same DNS servers on your desktop as you are on your server?

Are these domains internal domains or external domains?

have you run nslookup with set debug=on?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
dig +trace domain.com
```

From your (linux) command prompt on both machines.  This will show where each machine is getting the data as it queries the root servers, and each delegated sub-server until it finds (or doesn't find) these domains.

It could be anything from an incorrect SOA to a DNS server blocking your requests for that domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can occasionally run afoul of search lists. To eliminate that as a potential issue, terminate your lookup with a "."; i.e., `nslookup www.example.com.`

Additionally, double check that you're using the same nameservers on each box using `ipconfig /all` on a windows box or `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on a linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server running DNS service? What are the DNS setting of the server's network interfaces? Should be localhost. And DNS of your ISP should be set in forwarders.

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be a windows question, what does "ipconfig" report?  Does it list the DNS servers you expect to see?  Do the client and server differ?